# Git: List the branches for merge in progress

Tags: git, merge

My team programs in LabVIEW, which stores all of it's source code in binary files. This means when "merging" 99% of the time you're selection the file from the merge base, or the branch.

I'd like to make a visual tool the help with this (source tree is a little pokey in this situation). It will basically be just a UI that will run a bunch of the following commands:

```
git checkout --ours ...
git checkout --theirs ....
```

My question: is there any way to get the nice user friendly branch name that corresponds to "ours" and "theirs"?

Answer (score 0):

The `ours` branch is just the branch you were on when you started the merge, which is to say, whatever `HEAD` names.  (This assumes `HEAD` names a branch, i.e., that you are not on the special anonymous "detached HEAD" branch when you start the merge.)

To get the symbolic name of the current branch:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD
```

This prints the full name (`refs/heads/master`) to standard output and exits with success (zero) status, or prints a `fatal: ...` message to stderr and exits with failure (nonzero) status.  Add `-q` to suppress failure messages; add `--short` to suppress the `refs/heads/` part from the output on success.

The name(s), if any, of the *other* branch(es) being merged is/are a bit more difficult.  Git translates the arguments to raw SHA-1 hash IDs early on.  However, it *also* stores the names, if there were some, in `.git/MERGE_MSG`:

```
$ cat .git/MERGE_MSG
Merge branch 'BranchB' into BranchA
$
```

By reading and parsing that file (note: you can locate the `.git` directory with `git rev-parse --git-dir`, then add `/MERGE_MSG`, to get the path to the file) you can find the branch name, if there is one.  Note that this file's format (and indeed its existence) is not officially documented anywhere, so be prepared for it to change; but it has been there since relatively early days, unchanged for a long time.